# corrupt database & listbox problems

Tags: c#, database, listbox

im working in WinForms C#.

for some reason when I want to populate my listBox it stops and says my database is corrupt.
I have added a repair line and the codes run afterwards, but nothing happends. My listbox is not populated.

Here is the code im using.:

```
public void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlCeConnection cn = new SqlCeConnection(@"Data Source = Database1.mdf");
        cn.Open();
        SqlCeCommand cm = new SqlCeCommand("SELECT * FROM tblprojects ORDER BY Projekt_liste ASC", cn);

        try
        {
            SqlCeDataReader dr = cm.ExecuteReader();

            while (dr.Read())
            {
                ListBox project_list = Application.OpenForms["Form1"].Controls["tabControl1"].Controls["tabPage1"].Controls["Project_list"] as ListBox;
                project_list.Items.Add(dr["Projekt_liste"].ToString());
            }
            cn.Close();
            cn.Dispose();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
        }
    }

    public void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        SqlCeConnection cn = new SqlCeConnection();

        SqlCeEngine engine = new SqlCeEngine("Data Source = Database1.mdf");

        if (false == engine.Verify())
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Database is corrupted.");
            engine.Repair(null, RepairOption.RecoverAllPossibleRows);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Check out this Link as well 
http://www.mikeborozdin.com/post/Introducing-Microsoft-SQL-Server-Compact-Edition-%28Part-I%29.aspx

Comment: If you are only populating the ListBox with values from 1 row I would suggest changing your SELECT * to "Select Projekt_liste FROM tblprojects ORDER BY Projekt_liste ASC"

Comment: thanks. ill get that in mind. im still working on the link you sent me.

Comment: Why are you trying to load a LISTBOX using this ListBox project_list = Application.OpenForms["Form1"].Controls["tabControl1"].Controls["tabPage1"].Controls["Project_list"] as ListBox; just drop a list box on your form, and reference it by its name so for example lstBoxPrjItems and use the Add() Method to populate from sqldatareader... you need to Create a ListItem then assign it a value or values then add that ListItem to a ListBox

Comment: my listbox is on form1 and my add buton is on form2. I have no idea how to call the listbox on form1 from form2, besides the way I do it now :S

Comment: look at some of the examples .. If my still need help we can move forward from there.. you may want to change your Question and also explain that you are doing or using MDI and need to populate and or get items from the second form.. MDI is not difficult.. but try to get the load / read values working correctly first..

Comment: I hope that all of the information I provided was helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example if you want to load the items

```
1. make sure you have a ListBox on the winform
2. name the ListBox 
3. Create a ListItem 
4 Add the ListItem to the ListBox

while(dr.Read())
{
  ListViewItem obj=new ListViewItem(Convert.ToString(dr[0]),Convert.ToString(dr[1]);
  //in object of ListViewItem give display member at first and give value member at second position 
  listView1.Items.Add(obj); // add object to the listbox
}
```

Here are a few links that you can use as well to show different ways on how to populate a ListBox

one is Windows and the other will be if you are using or plan to use ASP.NET

[Populate a ListBox when using SQLDataReader](http://www.akadia.com/services/dotnet_data_reader.html)

[asp.net SqlDataReader example: how to use Read() method to populate ListBox](http://asp-net-example.blogspot.com/2008/12/aspnet-sqldatareader-example-how-to-use.html)

[Populate ASP.NET ListBox using SqlDataReader](http://www.dotnetcodecentral.com/Post/57/ado-net-querying-for-data/populate-asp-net-listbox-using-sqldatareader)

Answer (score 1):

From [Microsoft Site](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms172420.aspx)

> The Repair method does not guarantee complete data recovery for every
>   database. Some forms of data corruptions cannot be repaired
>   completely, regardless of the Repair option that is selected by the
>   application.

This could be one of the case where your file is corrupted.

Also please try To have repair call straight above the call to populate Data in List.

This may help.

Comment: Thanks DJ Kraze; Just did that

Comment: well. my database is not corrupted enymore after i moved the repair call.
but my list is still not populated :(